# fseek/ftell and stat.st_size doesn't return actual file size in text mode

Tags: c

platform: windows
o/s: XP sp3
compiler: gcc v4.8.1
text editor: notepad
encoding: ansi

question: how can i retreive the **actual** file size in text mode so that i can  set a buffer size **exactly**?

```
    char *filename = "functions.txt";

    FILE *source = fopen(filename,"r");

    struct stat properites;

    stat(filename,&properties);

    long size_stat = properties.st_size;

    fseek(source,0,SEEK_END);
    long size_ftell = ftell(source);
    fseek(source,0,SEEK_SET);

    char *pchar_source = malloc(sizeof(char)*size_stat);

    long size_read = fread(pchar_source,sizeof(char),size_stat,source);
```

**functions.txt**
tokenize(String string, Character delimiter) String[]
{

}

**output**
file size-stat [70]
file size-ftell [70]
file size-fread [67]

for small files, the difference is negligible, however, for file larger files, this means unneccessay memory allocation.  any suggestions?

one possible solution:

```
long fileSize  = 0;

while (getc(source) != EOF)
{
    fileSize++;
}
```

however, this is very wasteful and time consuming for large files.

Answer (score 4):

`ftell` gives you the correct size in bytes. As others noted, it is because you have three line endings encoded as `\r\n`. When you open in text mode on Windows, they get converted to `\n`, thus you read three chars less.

There are two options I see:

1. Use `ftell` as an estimate for the size of the buffer, but then, after the `fread`, use `size_read` in the rest of your code for the buffer size. You will just waste *number-of-lines* bytes of memory, which is not a big deal.
2. Open the file in binary mode `rb`. You will get a size of 70, but also `fread` will return 70 bytes. Then write your code with the understanding that line endings might be `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`.

From the above two I really recommend the 2nd option: it gives a more robust and portable program, and the notion of binary mode is less confusing than the platform dependent text-mode.

Comment: i guess im not being clear enough.  i have a file, lets say its 500MB.  its saved in notepad as ANSI. ftell and stat_st.size say its 500MB so i set my buffer to that size.  however, when i read it, its only 200MB given, as youve noted, the conversion.  i realise this.  my point is, there is no point creating a 500MB buffer if you only need 200MB.  can it be done?

Comment: id also like to add, that in the 3 days ive been searching for an answer, nowhere is the literature has it mentioned "ESTIMATE".  so tell me, when an estimate is made, was is the error margin?

Comment: you wrote: "You will just waste number-of-lines bytes of memory, which is not a big deal."  i beg to differ.  i have a 160,921,728 byte file (stat.st_size and ftell).  read says: 156,458,752 a "small" difference of 4,462,976 bytes.  are you saying this is acceptable?

Comment: @johnny If the 4,462,976 bytes is a problem, then call `realloc` on the buffer once you know the real size. The standard specifically states that the information provided by `ftell` for text files is "unspecified", so you won't find an solution using it.

Comment: @krueger, lol, im sorry i had to.  dont you think 2.7% of unnecessary memory allocation is a problem?  having read countless articles, both here and elsewhere, i understand how to use ftell and the like.  however, what i want to know is whether or not theres a function or a more accurate way of doing things rather than reallocate or using a "temporary size".  reallocation is fine for one file, 10 or more and it becomes a problem.  "theres enough memory nowdays johnny, dont worry about it.", i hear you say. "waste a little here, waste a little there soon it becomes, i need more".

Comment: @johnny: then *improve* your code. Do not read the entire file at once *nor* one byte at a time. Pick a reasonably sized buffer (more than your -expected- average line length), read a buffer-full, strip the extra LFs and store what you need. No big deal -- you are optimizing memory usage with only a small extra cost in reading.

Comment: @johnny: If your file is pure text, then you cannot get 200MB from 500MB, at most 250MB. The "margin error" is 50%, which is the case when your file consists entirely of empty lines. Yes, 2.7% waste of memory is *not* a problem. There are lots of places where your system "wastes" significant amounts of memory for the sake of performance or simplicity: alignment of allocations, preallocations of dynamically growing arrays, etc... Seriously, when even my cell-phone has 2GB of memory, wasting 4MB during processing of 150MB file is negligible.

Comment: @ybungalobill, sweety, i mayve slightly exaggerated the 500 and 200 sizes.  see above for actual sizes.  its good that you mention "empty lines" because im writing a compiler and there will be many many empty lines.  also, like ive mentioned several time already, one small file is fine, but if theres more, and there will be, 2.7% turns into 27%, available memory turns into page files.  i wouldve thought torvalds made a point of waste.  i guess i was wrong.

Comment: @Jongware "improve your code"......thats why i asked the question!  if i have to process one byte at a time, it makes it hard not to.  im writing my first compiler.  are you suggesting i read and process (remove) valid comment while i read two bytes at a time?  if not, kindly explain what you mean.

Comment: @johnny: you can consider [memory mapping the file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Answer (score 1):

If the "size" of the file is to be given in units that depend on the file's contents, then accurately determining that size requires scanning the entire file.

That is precisely the situation for any file opened in text mode on Windows (because physical "\r\n" is treated as a single logical unit).  It is also the case if the file content is encoded in some way, and you want the count of decoded units.  That's not as unlikely as it may sound, as it arises quite frequently with character encodings, such as (21-bit) Unicode characters encoded as a UTF-8 byte stream.

As far as creating a buffer to hold the whole file content,

1. If you have to worry about large files, then do everything possible to avoid creating such a buffer in the first place.  Ideally, you would process the file in a streaming mode, so that you don't have to keep much of it in memory at any one time.
2. If you must create such a buffer, then consider a buffer consisting of a linked list of smallish blocks (say 4 - 32k), so that you can extend the buffer as needed without `realloc()` (e.g. as needed while reading the file).

Comment: you probably posted your comment while i was answering my own question detailing exactly what you and others have written.  my point to all this is, that its ridiculous that you cant  get the actual file size UNTIL youve read a file.  i think its important that others know this and dont suffer the same frustrations i did.

Comment: @johnny: the *actual* file size is what `ftell` and `stat` returns. What `fread` returns for the `r` mode on Windows is a result of a perverted understanding of what files are. You should simply use the `rb` mode and that's it.

Comment: @ybungalobill, if ftell or stat.st_size gives you the "actual" size, then what does fread return?  what would you call it?

Comment: @ybungalobill element being what exactly?  any printable character?

Answer (score -2):

**answer:**
no you cant.

the actual file size, and not an "estimate", is only available after a complete read.  this is due to conversions (if any) of new lines and encoding types.  for those wondering, here is the "proper" way of determining the actual file size.

```
    char *filename = "sample.txt";
    FILE *file_source = fopen(filename,"r"); // can be set to either "r" or "rb"

    // use stat.st_size if you have the library <sys/stat.h>
    struct stat stat_sourceFile;

    stat(filename,&stat_sourceFile);

    long long_fileSize_stat = stat_sourceFile.st_size;  // estimate only

    // use fseek,ftell,fseek if you dont have the lib <sys/stat.h>
    fseek(file_source,0,SEEK_END);
    long long_fileSize_ftell = ftell(file_source);  // estimate only
    fseek(file_source,0,SEEK_SET);

    char *pchar_source = malloc(sizeof(char)*long_fileSize_stat);

    long long_ACTUAL_FILE_SIZE = fread(pchar_source,sizeof(char),long_fileSize_stat,file_source);

    realloc(pchar_source,long_ACTUAL_FILE_SIZE);

    //  now when we pass the pointer/array size to ANY function/method, you WONT 
    //  get those funny characters not part of your file at the end of your
    //  printf statements.  also, instead of using long_ACTUAL_FILE_SIZE as
    //  the bounds for iteration, you could use strlen(pchar_source)
```

hope this helps others new to c and file buffering.